# PHP $array[]=$content not working as it ought

Tags: php, arrays

Okay, I have been tearing my hair (and beard) out at this one for a good hour or more now. I can't work out why it isn't working, particularly as it's exactly the same code I use elsewhere which *does* work.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `aio_log` ORDER BY `log_timestamp` DESC LIMIT 10;"; // A 'WHERE' will be put in here
$logs = array();
$one_log = array();

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($one_log['id'], $one_log['timestamp'],     $one_log['headline'],
                     $one_log['text'], $one_log['link'], $one_log['font_awesome'],
                     $one_log['type']);

  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($one_log['link'] == "") $one_log['link'] = '#';
    // print_r($one_log); shows the expected output of the database row.
    $logs[] = $one_log;
    //array_push($logs, $one_log); // gives the same - incorrect - response as the above line
  }
}
print_r($logs); // Shows the right number of returned rows from the database, but all showing
// an identical content of the last database row returned.
```

Probably the only difference between this code and code I've used elsewhere is that this one doesn't have any binded parts of the SQL statement as it's a simple 'select everything no matter what' statement, but as the `print_r($one_log)` bit works fine, I cannot see this being the issue. The issue is obviously somewhere in the `$logs[] = $one_log` bit, but as I've used it elsewhere, and get exactly the same result using `array_push`, I'm at my wits end here!

Ideas folks?

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with arguments being passed by reference. If you read the comments at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php, you will see somebody had the same issue (// don't know why, but when I tried $array[] = $data, I got the same one result in all rows) and found a way around it.

Comment: @CapeStar: Not sure that would work in this instance as I believe it would give me a large 1D array with all the data instead of the 2D one I want. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @DavidAman: it could be that. Strange that it works elsewhere in my code, but not here. Anyway - Barmar's answer below also answers the question and has worked for what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very strange. The assignment

```
$logs[] = $one_log;
```

is supposed to make a copy of `$one_log` when it pushes it onto the array. But apparently this isn't interacting as expected with the fact that `bind_param` binds references to the variables -- when you fetch the new row, the references are apparently referring to the copy as well as the original. This is probably a weird consequence of the way that PHP uses copy-on-write; updating the reference seems not to be considered a write that triggers the copy.

I suggest you use normal variables instead of the `$one_log` array.

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $timestamp, $headline, $text, $link, $font_awesome, $type);
```

and then in the fetch loop use:

```
$logs[] = array('id' => $id, 'timestamp' => $timestamp, 'headline' => $headline, 
                'text' => $text, 'link' => $link, 'font_awesome' => $font_awesome, 
                'type' => $type);
```

Comment: Glad to see that I'm not the only one who had this problem. Still can't work out why it works elsewhere and not here. I did think it was perhaps I use it in a function elsewhere, so stuck this into a function but still no. (It's actually probably better to functionise it anyway!) So now, the _only_ difference is that I don't have a `$stmt->bind_param` in this particular code whereas I do in other instances.  I've done it the way you suggested and it works fine now.

Comment: As an addition, is it my imagination, or is extracting data from a MySQL database in PHP not as easy with MySQLi as it was with the older (albeit less secure) functions? Oh for the days when you could do `mysql_fetch_array`!!!

Comment: @RichardGraham You can use `mysqli_fetch_array`. But unless you have the MYSQLND driver you can't use that with prepared statements. I generally prefer PDO.

Comment: that's what I've heard, but attempting to use it implies that it's not on my system!